# Limitar la cantidad de fotos que se muestran en un celular en una galería adaptable

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, css3

Tengo una galería realizada con Bootstrap v3.1.0 (para que sea [adaptable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dise%C3%B1o_web_adaptable), más que nada) y quiero que cuando se vea la página desde el celular se muestren solo 4 fotos en vez de las 11.

Lo que tengo de código HTML es esto:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes1.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes2.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes3.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes4.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes5.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes6.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes7.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes8.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes9.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/Clientes10.jpg" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <a href="https://www.discorweb.com"><img src="images/Clientes11.jpg"
                    alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif"></a>
```

Y lo de CSS no lo adjunto, ya que utilizo Bootstrap.

¿Me podrían dar una idea cómo limitar la cantidad de fotos que aparecen cuando se visualiza con el celular?

Comment: Necesitamos saber que versión de bootstrap usas

Comment: Listo @CristianCamilo. La versión es v3.1.0 y ya lo modifiqué arriba

Comment: ¿Ese listado es estático o lo generas en el lado del servidor mediante ASP, PHP, JSP, Python, etc? Y, además, ¿cuál es la etiqueta padre de este listado de imágenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando la ultima versión de Bootstrap solo debes añadir estas clases a los elementos que no quieres ver en Mobile

```
d-none d-sm-block
```

Si no estoy mal en la version 3.4 para abajo se usaban las clases

```
hidden-xs
```

Answer (score 2):

### ¿Me podrían dar una idea cómo limitar la cantidad de fotos que aparecen cuando se visualiza con el celular?

En el CSS de Bootstrap una tableta (`screen-md`) está definida como toda pantalla con un ancho [superior a `768px`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.0/less/variables.less#L267) e [inferior a `992px`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.0/less/variables.less#L273).

Eso significa que todo lo que esté por debajo de `768px` se considera un móvil, por lo que puedes usar una regla de [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) para ocultar todos aquellos a partir del cuarto elemento de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Solo en dispositivos móviles */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Ocultamos a partir del quinto elemento */
  #listado > div:nth-child(n+5) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en este ejemplo:

```css
/* Mostramos un borde verde alrededor de todos los elementos */
#listado > div {
  border: 1px green solid;
}

/* Solo en dispositivos móviles */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Ocultamos a partir del quinto elemento */
  #listado > div:nth-child(n+5) {
    display: none;
  }
  /* El último lo muestro */
  #listado > div:last-child {
    display: block;
    border: 1px blue solid;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-ecYLBGh5iQPKkdBijp+tVHMkFR2N2XfbsE83/9nFM/qwSLsjAPGRl7z+jpAWj5Enw2s4NS+9hHb/VxhP1CUYjQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="listado">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/32px-Psi_icon_new.png" alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a href="https://www.discorweb.com"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Psi_icon_new.png/48px-Psi_icon_new.png"
                alt="Nuestros Clientes del Estudio Aclif" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-ZcSe9wnTqZw/YStrDL1FFDDP/GCvfAYJ8y10Z7wYERPswtWAHorWzJNUgrfVmVDiIDwJHp3xL/yCoy7EqdbYTg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

PD: He usado `:last-child` para que no se oculte el último elemento, que es un enlace a una página. Supongo que no querrás que se oculte junto con el resto de imágenes.

---

Si en vez de limitar el número de elementos que se muestran en un dispositivo móvil deseas elegir cuáles se ocultarán y cuales no, para ello existe la clase [`hidden-xs`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.0/less/responsive-utilities.less#L55).

Dicha clase impone un [`display: none !important;`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.0/less/mixins.less#L631) en aquellos elementos que no desees visualizar en dispositivos móviles.